# Clipping sf vector by terra raster extent with R

Tags: raster, r, sf, terra

I am trying to do something fairly simple: I want to clip a vector with point features down to only features that are contained within a raster extent. For raster I am using the package terra, for vector the package sf. I am surprised how interoperable these two common packages are in this regard, seeing that `extract(terra::SpatRast, sf::sf_vector_df)` works just fine.

My approaches so far have led to only errors. What is a good way to make a terra::raster extent and a sf-vector-dataset interoperable?

```
vhm = rast("xy.tif")
centers = st_read("centers.shp")

# trying straightforward
centers_vhm = st_intersection(centers, vhm)
>> Error in UseMethod("st_geometry") : no applicable method for 'st_geometry' applied to an object of class "SpatRaster"

# trying with extent
centers_vhm = st_intersection(centers, ext(vhm))
>> Error in geos_op2_geom("intersection", x, y, ...) : 
  st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) ist nicht TRUE

# trying to convert extent to sf object to assign CRS...
vhm_extent = st_as_sf(ext(vhm))
>> Error in UseMethod("st_as_sf") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_as_sf' applied to an object of class "SpatExtent"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start with the bounding box of your raster via `sf::st_bbox()` and cast it to `sfc` object via `sf::st_as_sfc()`. `sfc` objects can be used to clip a sf vector shapefile.

```
library(sf)
library(terra)

# a raster, any raster...
raster <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
# a vector, any vector...
vector <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries()

# this is the action!
bbox <- st_bbox(raster) %>% 
  st_as_sfc()

isection <- st_intersection(vector, bbox)

# validate results
mapview::mapview(isection, zcol = "NAME_ENGL")
```

[image: image of world countries clipped to the extent of elevation of Luxembourg raster]